# Jquery scrolling image top to bottom direction

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

I have the following code to scroll images in vertical direction (uses [jCarouselLite](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/))

Code:

```
$('#image').jCarouselLite({
    speed:    1000,
    visible:  1,
    circular: true,
    auto:     5000,
    scroll:   1,
    vertical: true
});
```

Needs:

This code allows the image to scroll bottom to top direction. I want to scroll image in reverse direction.[Top to Bottom]

Geetha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the only thing you are using jCarousel Lite for or more specifically the auto scroll feature you can simply update the auto extension the following code

starting at line 274 of jcarousellite_1.0.1.js

```
if(o.auto)
    setInterval(function() {
        go(curr+o.scroll);
    }, o.auto+o.speed);
```

with

```
if(o.auto)
    setInterval(function() {
        go(curr-o.scroll);
    }, o.auto+o.speed);
```

This is the quick and dirty way, i personally would take the time to write my own 'autoReverse' extension to not loose any existing functionality.

Comment: Is it possible to give fade effect using this plugin

Answer (score 1):

answered here [How to make JCarousel Vertical Scroller reverse scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819464/how-to-make-jcarousel-vertical-scroller-reverse-scroll/4515632#4515632) by matt ryan

```
$('#carousel').jcarousel({
    vertical: true,
    scroll: -1,
});
```