# How to make JCarousel Vertical Scroller reverse scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

I was able to instantiate a working scroller using jQuery Jcarousel however I need it to reverse scroll. For example right now I have:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        auto: 1,
        vertical: true,
        scroll: 1,
        animation: "slow",
        wrap: 'last',
        initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback
    }); 
});
```

What do I need to do to make the items scroll upwards instead of downwards?

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse autoscrolling is not implemented yet although you can code it quite easily.

This is the autoscrolling function in jCarousel:

```
/**
 * Starts autoscrolling.
 *
 * @method auto
 * @return undefined
 * @param s {Number} Seconds to periodically autoscroll the content.
 */
    startAuto: function(s) {
        if (s != undefined)
            this.options.auto = s;

        if (this.options.auto == 0)
            return this.stopAuto();

        if (this.timer != null)
            return;

        var self = this;
        this.timer = setTimeout(function() { self.next(); }, this.options.auto * 1000);
    },
```

(Lines 687 to 706 in [jquery.carousel.js](http://github.com/jsor/jcarousel/blob/master/lib/jquery.jcarousel.js) )

Changing `self.next();` to `self.prev()` should to the trick (can't test it right now, if you do please post the results).

Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response. I specifically changed line # 705 to : this.timer = setTimeout(function() { self.prev(); }, this.options.auto * 1000);

Now the scroller does not scroll and I am not getting any errors in Firebug.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhh I had to specifically use the 'start' option and set my index manually since it was starting from 1 and had nothing "previous" to go back to. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

actually, it's more simple than that.

```
scroll: -1
```

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Just to add this to XaviEsteve answer (I can't find a place to add comment to his answer anyway).

Once I've changed self.next() to self.prev(), I have to change 'wrap' option to 'both' to make it work for me, like this.

```
jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        auto: 1,
        wrap: 'both',
        vertical: true, 
        scroll: 1,
        start: 30,
        initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it should work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
      vertical: true,
      wrap: 'circular',
      animate: 'slow',
    });  
    $('#mycarousel').jcarouselAutoscroll({
      interval: 3000,
      target: '-=1', /*if you change - on + it will scroll up*/
      autostart: true
  });
});
```